# Get text between last forward slash and then before first hyphen

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I need to parse a URL, and get 1585710 from :

```
http://www.example.com/0/100013573/1585710-key-description-goes-here
```

So that means it's between the last / and before the first -

I have very little experience with regex, it's a really hard concept for me to understand.

Any help or assistance would be much appreciated

Edit: Using Python.

Comment: Which programming language are you using ? different languages have different flavors of regex!

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know that! I'm using Python :-)

Comment: For example, `(?<=\/)[^\/-]*(?=[^\/]*$)` works amazingly for Ruby (no need for capture groups); but Python doesn't have lookbehind, so you need to settle for capturing a part of the match.

Comment: So regex is implemented into every language separately? Are there any standards or just those set by "the main languages"?

Comment: There's several big libraries that get shared by some languages (notably PCRE and Oniguruma); but there are many languages that implement them from scratch. There are some things a regexp implementation must have (as a basic implementation of the mathematical idea of regular expressions), and then there's extensions that different languages implement to a smaller or larger degree (most of them departing from mathematical regular expressions, some departing significantly, giving regexps much more power).

Comment: @Amadan lookbehinds are supported by python. `re.search(r'(?<=\/)[^\/-]*(?=[^\/]*$)', s).group()` . If your lookbehind contain quantifier then you need to import `regex` module which supports quantifiers inside lookbehind.

Comment: By the way, if you wish to learn more, read through [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) while following with experiments in a console of your choice.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I am, apparently, an idiot! Thank you (obviously, I'm not great in Python :p ) Also, escapes for slashes are not needed.

Comment: Note that regex certainly isn't the only way to get where you're going: `url.split("/")[-1].split("-")[0]` will work too.

Comment: Wow, DSM that's fantastic. What does the [-1] do?

Comment: @Amadan: look-arounds are cool when they are needed, but its amazing how often complicated regexen are built with lookarounds when a simple really regular expression would work just fine; in this case, `.*/([^-]*)-`

Comment: @rici: Yes, I upvoted Avinash's answer already. Just saying, with lookarounds you don't need grouping, and you can work exactly on the match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the below regex and get the number from group index 1.

```
^.*\/([^-]*)-.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nX9aI9/5)

Code:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "http://www.example.com/0/100013573/1585710-key-description-goes-here"
>>> m = re.search(r'^.*\/([^-]*)-.*$', s, re.M)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f8a51f07558>
>>> m.group(1)
'1585710'
>>> m = re.search(r'.*\/([^-]*)-.*', s)
>>> m.group(1)
'1585710'
>>> m = re.search(r'.*\/([^-]*)', s)
>>> m.group(1)
'1585710'
```

**Explanation:**

- `.*\/` Matches all the characters upto the last `/` symbol.
- `([^-]*)` Captures any character but not of `-` zero or more times.
- `-.*` Matches all the remaining characters.
- `group(1)` contains the characters which are captured by the first capturing group. Printing the group(1) will give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you need to find any strings between a `/` and a `-`, you could simply do:

`/.*-`

Since `.` is any char, and `*` is any amount. However, this poses a problem, because you could get the whole `/www.example.com/0/100013573/1585710-key-description-goes`, which is between `/` and a `-`. So, what you need to do is to search for anything that is not a `/` and `-`:

`/[^/-]*-`

`^` means no, and anything between `[]` is, roughly, an OR list.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: No, it doesn't help, as user rici mentioned, when you have a `-` in your url name (as in `www.lala-lele.com`).

To make sure is the last `/` you got, you can match the rest of your string, making sure it doesn't have any `/` in it until the end (`$`), as in:

`/[^/-]*-[^/]*$`

And, to get just the string inside it, you can:

`/\([^/-]*\)-[^/]*$`

Since `\(` and `\)` specify what you want as the output of your regex.

Comment: OP wants the string between the *last* slash and the next dash. Your regex will fail, for example, on `/www.best-example.com/0/100013573/1585710-key-description-goes`

Answer (score 1):

You can use matching groups in order to extract the number with the regex `\/(\d+)-`:

```
import re
s = 'http://www.example.com/0/100013573/1585710-key-description-goes-here'
m = re.search(r'\/(\d+)-', s)
print m.group(1) # 1585710
```

Check out the **[Fiddler](http://regex101.com/r/nX9aI9/6)**